# FBAuth not working Swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I'm trying to add authentication via Facebook onto my app, within my plist I have:

```
  <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb146156719258538</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>146156719258538</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>applicationTest</string>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

In my AppDelegate I have a method:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    let appId = FBSDKSettings.appID()

    print("app id:" + appId!)
    print("url id:" + String(url.scheme!.hasPrefix("fb\(appId)")))
    print("url host:" + String(describing: url.host))

    if url.scheme != nil && url.scheme!.hasPrefix("fb\(appId)") && url.host ==  "authorize" { // facebook
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options)
    }
    return false
}
```

When the FB login button is clicked in my ViewController, you would then expect the code within the IF statement of the AppDelegate method to be executed. However this returns false, i've debugged the code and it appears that the line:

```
url.scheme!.hasPrefix("fb\(appId)")
```

Is returning false even though the correct appId is being printed.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

P.S: Printing the url.scheme gives:

fb146156719258538

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured the settings on your Facebook account correctly?

Comment: Yes I have added an application there